# JUnit 5 suites do not run parallel

Tags: java, concurrency, automated-tests, integration-testing, junit5

I have a parent suite, that includes child suites, which themselves include different tests (the same test may be included in multiple child suites). If I enable concurreny, only those tests inside a child suites are running parallel. The child suites themselve are not running parallel. But I want the child suites to run parallel also (or just the child suites).

Parent suite:

```
@Suite
@IncludeTags({"DifferentTagsUsedInTests"})
@SelectClasses({ChildSuiteA.class, ChildSuiteB.class})
@ConfigurationParameter(key = "config for all tests", value = "within this suite")
public class ParentSuite {}
```

Child suite:

```
@Suite
@IncludeTags({"DifferentTagsUsedInTests"})
@SelectPackages("my.tests")
@ConfigurationParameter(key = "additional config for all tests", value = "within this suite")
public class ChildSuiteA {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the JUnit Platform Suite Engine doesn't support parallel execution.

Conceptually JUnit 5 consists of the JUnit Platform + Several Test Engines. The property that you've used to enable parallel execution is prefixed with `junit.jupiter.`. This shows that it only applies to the Jupiter Engine, not the Suite Engine. And there is no equivalent property for the Suite Engine.